# ActiveRecord attribute value cannot be overwritten

Tags: php, yii, http-post, yii-cactiverecord

I'm working with Yii. In my controller I use the following code to update my model attribute values with my POST input values:

```
$foo->attributes = $_POST['Foo'][$i];
```

This overrides all my attributes, except one. I cannot figure out why it won't override that single one.

Table structure:

```
price (decimal 11,2)
amount (int 11)
period (varchar 255)
```

I cannot override the `amount` field, not even manually. Is it because of it being an `int`? I haven't had issues with `int` before though.

I have used `var_dump()` to check the contents of both `$foo->attributes` and `$_POST['Foo'][$i]` and they are correct and all filled in. It just won't override the `amount` in `$foo->attributes`.

**Validation rules**

```
array('period, price', 'required'),
array('amount', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
array('period', 'length', 'max'=>255),
array('price, amount', 'length', 'max'=>10),
array('amount, period, price', 'safe', 'on'=>'search')
```

`amount` should always be an integer. Testing values were 10, 20, 30.

**Example of issue**

```
var_dump( $foo->attributes );
var_dump( $_POST['Foo'][$i] );
$foo->attributes = $_POST['Foo'][$i];
var_dump( $foo->attributes );
```

Outputs the following:

```
//$foo->attributes 
array (size=3)
  'price' => string '140.00' (length=6)
  'amount' => string '10' (length=2)
  'period' => string 'monthly' (length=6)

//$_POST['Foo'][$i]
array (size=3)
  'price' => string '150.00' (length=6)
  'amount' => string '20' (length=2)
  'period' => string 'yearly' (length=6)

//$foo->attributes after rebinding
array (size=3)
  'price' => string '150.00' (length=6)
  'amount' => string '10' (length=2)
  'period' => string 'yearly' (length=6)
```

There are some additional fields in there. For example the model has a few more fields that the `$_POST` array doesn't have, but they seem to merge nicely. Should I add these too or are they irrelevant?

Comment: well ... start digging https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.14/framework/db/ar/CActiveRecord.php#L154

Comment: I would suggest you change the field from an integer to a decimal. If your amount is say 2.3, then this will not work with integer. Only whole Numbers (integers) ie 1,2,16,29 will work.

Comment: @JonPaulH The amount field can only be whole numbers.

Comment: What happens if you do say, $foo->amount = 10; $foo->save();

Comment: @JonPaulH that works, but `$foo->amount = $_POST['Foo'][$i]['amount'];` doesn't x.x

Comment: Can you show the result of `$foo->getAttributes()` after binding?

Comment: ok does this work
$foo->attributes = $_POST['Foo'][$i];
$foo->amount = 10;
$foo->save();

Please then check

$foo->attributes = $_POST['Foo'][$i];
$_POST['Foo'][$i]['amount'] = 10;
$foo->amount = $_POST['Foo'][$i]['amount'];
$foo->save();

Comment: @CreatoR added example in first post. Jon Paul H: hard to read that without formatting x.x

Comment: @JonPaulH after testing, `$foo->attributes = $_POST['Foo'][$i];  $foo->amount = $_POST['Foo'][$i]['amount'];` works. But it seems very weird that I have to do this.

Comment: @DarkAshelin agreed. I wish I could help more, but this also makes no sense to me as to why this method works and the other one doesn't. If I find anything I'll add a comment.

Comment: It's very interesting to see var_dump of your $_POST, I think your handling it wrong $_POST['Foo'][$i] ?

Comment: @tinyByte It is in context of tabular input data. `$_POST['Foo']` is an array, of which I loop over and then access the input values through `$i`. Reference: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/form.table

Comment: Can you show this ActiveRecord, I think you have some behaviors before setting attributes

Comment: @CreatoR Here is the Model: http://pastebin.com/8Lp1DngF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Temporary solution

In the end I used the following (temporary) solution, but it is very odd that I actually need to set the value twice before it works:

```
$foo->attributes = $_POST['Foo'][$i];
$foo->amount = $_POST['Foo'][$i]['amount'];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're using validation for fields `price`, `period`, but not for `amount`. You have 2 way:

- use `$foo->setAttributes($_POST['Foo'][$i], false)` - not recommend
- add `amount` to validation rules as: `array('amount', 'safe')`, or better: `array('amount', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>false),)`

OR
You haven't `amount` in attributes list of the model Foo

Comment: Added my current validation rules in the first post.

Comment: I'm update answer: change validation rule to `array('amount', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>false)`

Comment: Please, do `var_dump($foo->getErrors())` after binding

Comment: `$foo->getErrors()` outputs an empty array.

Comment: it's very strange, and the last - try to change validation rule of `amount` to `array('amount', 'safe')` and try again

Answer (score 0):

check for your rules first for your scenario!

I suppose by attributes you mean one of your price amount period attributes, right. you can do like:

```
$foo->setAttributes(array(
    'price' => $_POST['Foo']['price'],
    'period' => $_POST['Foo']['period'],
    'amount' => $_POST['Foo']['amount'],
));
```

or simply

```
$foo->amount = $_POST['Foo']['amount'];
```

UPDATE: try changing

```
$foo->attributes = $_POST['Foo'][$i]
```

to

```
$foo->setAttributes($_POST['Foo']);
```

Comment: I've tried that, but it still doesn't work; doesn't override the attribute value for `amount`.

Comment: No, it didn't. But after testing a bit, I found that `$foo->attributes = $_POST['Foo'][$i]; $foo->amount = $_POST['Foo'][$i]['amount'];` does work. It just seems very odd that I need to set it twice before it works.

Comment: $foo->attributes is not for setting values,setAttributes() is for doing that

Comment: well using either didn't make a difference.

Comment: (Sidenote: I was using `$foo->attributes` for setting the values because this is how it is noted in the official Yii docs)

Comment: if it's tabular input then $foo->setAttributes($_POST['Foo'][$i]); sould do the trick, please post your var_dump($_POST)

Comment: I don't see how the entire POST dump is relevant. `$_POST['Foo']` is an array containing more arrays. Your suggested code doesn't work, and I already added a dump of the `$_POST['Foo'][$i]` array.

Comment: @Dark Ashelin In every case , you emphasized that everything is correct. First thing, you said you can save $foo->amount when you set directly value for it. You also checked that $_POST['Foo'][$i]['amount'] contains a value absolutely. Last thing,  "array('amount', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true)," in your model is fine, it made sure you are capable of setting amount properly through ->attributes (I have done example in myself to make sure it worked fine). I just disquiet that in one of above things, maybe some of dump times for result made you confused it was right while it was not

Comment: @TelvinNguyen Actually, `$foo->amount` by itself did not work for setting the value. It only works after setting it twice as shown in the Temporary solution in the first post. I can give you a full dump of the POST as well as the model, but how do I avoid the dump hiding nested arrays without showing the content?